# Installing Modules in Anaconda3

Tags: python, anaconda

Halloo

Alright, I've been wracking my brains and trying over and over again, but I cannot install any modules for my Anaconda Python 3.5.  I have tried everything under the sun.  After looking around people either recomend using pip install while in the Anaconda\Scripts directory, while other just say to use the "conda" command.  Neither work.  When using the conda, sometimes, this would happen

```
$Anaconda3> conda install -c anaconda quandl=2.8.9
$Fetching package metadata: ........Error: Could not find URL: http://www.pygame.org/pcr/win-64/
```

This is especially notable to me because before I spent hours upon hours trying instal pygame before to no avail, but this was months ago.

In other cases, this would happen:

```
$Fetching package metadata: .........An unexpected error has occurred, please consider sending the following traceback to the conda GitHub issue tracker at:

https://github.com/conda/conda/issues

Include the output of the command 'conda info' in your report.


Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda\Scripts\conda-script.py", line 4, in <module>
sys.exit(main())
File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 194, in main
args_func(args, p)
File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 201, in args_func
args.func(args, p)
File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda\lib\site-      packages\conda\cli\main_install.py", line 45, in execute
install.install(args, parser, 'install')
 File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\install.py", line 244, in install
offline=args.offline)
 File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\common.py",    line 548, in get_index_trap
return get_index(*args, **kwargs)
 File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\conda\api.py", line 42, in get_index
unknown=unknown)
File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\conda\utils.py", line 119, in __call__
value = self.func(*args, **kw)
File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\conda\fetch.py", line 255, in fetch_index
repodatas.append((url, future.result()))
 File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 407, in result
return self.__get_result()
File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda\lib\site-    packages\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 359, in __get_result
reraise(self._exception, self._traceback)
File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda\lib\site-  packages\concurrent\futures\_compat.py", line 107, in reraise
exec('raise exc_type, exc_value, traceback', {}, locals_)
File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\concurrent\futures\thread.py", line 61, in run
```

etc..., it goes on for quite a bit.

Furthermore, if I tried to use a pip install inside the \Anaconda3\Scripts and it actually went, for some reason, and installed it in my Anaconda folder for Python 2.7, but not in Python3 (I just found this out while typing this).  So, I'm still stuck that I don't have my quandl module for Python 3.  Can anyone please help me fix this issue?  Everytime I try to back to learn some programming, it's the packages and modules to keep killing me and wasting hours upon hours of my time.  If I can just get over this issue, it would make all the difference.  Thanks!

Comment: Please refer to [managing environments](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/using/envs.html), then [managing packages](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/using/pkgs.html) to install to the correct anaconda environment

Comment: @Scratch'N'Purr Thanks, but I've already looked at it and it doesn't seem to give me what I need.  I looked at the part about creating and managing environments, but even when I tried to make a new environment using python 3, I got a very similar result: 
`Anaconda3> conda create --name PY3 python=3
Fetching package metadata: ........Error: Could not find URL: http://www.pygame.org/pcr/win-64/`

I've been making efforts to learn programming over the past year or two, but the thing that keep coming in my way are these horrible package and module issues.  Please help.

Comment: Are you running the conda install command within the Anaconda command line interface by the way? You should be using the install command in windows powershell or windows command terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
conda create -n quandl-env python=3.5
activate quandl-env
conda install --override-channels --channel anaconda quandl=2.8.9
```

It looks like you have a bad channel (http://www.pygame.org/pcr/win-64/) in your conda config. What does `conda config --get` return?  I suspect that you will see that pygame channel there which doesn't appear to work. You can remove it from your `.condarc` file or via `conda config --remove`.

You probably only want to have the default channels. You can try editing your `.condarc` file which should be in your home directory (`C:\Users\..`). Edit it so that it looks like this:

```
channels:
- defaults
```

**Updated:** Fixed the `conda config` usage, more explanation on the .condarc, and added an environment creation to make sure this package is being installed in a 3.5 environment.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It seems to have worked...But for my Python 2.7, not for Python 3. Also, in answer to your question `conda config --channels --get
usage: conda-script.py [-h] [-V] [--debug] command ...
conda-script.py: error: unrecognized arguments: --channels`

Comment: Sorry, that should have been `conda config --get`.  I'll update.

Comment: Ok, I changed the .condarc file and that seems to have improved the situation greatly.  I used `$conda install quandl` and it installed it to my Python 2.7 nicely.  So, one issue seems to have been fixed.  Also `conda config --get --add channels 'defaults'`.  So this seems fine.  On the other hand, when I tried using your code `conda create -n quandl-env python=3.5` It results in getting this `Fetching package metadata: ...An unexpected error has occurred, please consider sending the
following traceback to the conda GitHub issue tracker at:

    https://github.com/conda/conda/issues`

Comment: Actually, I managed to fix it :D. It turns out I had python 3.5.1, not 3.5 and apparently that makes a world of difference.  In any case, it is currently installing the environment.  Thanks a million for your help! Quick question, how do I switch between these environments?

Comment: You can see all your environments with `conda env list`. Let's call "X" one of the environments listed.  You can enter any of those environments with `activate X` in windows or `source activate X` in linux.  You can exit the environment with `deactivate` in windows and `source deactivate` in linux.